# Cambiar el launch browswer en R

Tags: r

Estoy utilizando el paquete treetop... y me lanza una especie shiny..
Este el codigo que uso:

```
treetop::launchApp(launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Estoy intentando cambiar el launch browser para que el shyni se ejecute en mozila o chrome y no en el edge:
Como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisamos el código de [`launchApp()`](https://github.com/carlos-alberto-silva/weblidar-treetop/blob/master/R/launchApp.R) vemos que simplemente se invoca [`shinny:runApp()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.13.0/runApp.html) y para el parámetro `launch.browser` leemos en la ayuda:

> **launch.browser**    If true, the system's default web browser will be launched automatically after the app is started. Defaults to true in
> interactive sessions only. This value of this parameter can also be a
> function to call with the application's URL.

Es decir, en caso de `TRUE` se lanzará el navegador por defecto del sistema operativo anfitrión, por lo que deberías cambiar esto desde tu sistema, o eventualmente, si tienes localizado el `path` del navegador deseado, podrías configurar el navegador por defecto de la sesión de R mediante algo así:

```
options(browser = "/usr/bin/firefox") # Establecemos el browser default
treetop::launchApp(launch.browser = TRUE)
```